# Can not resolve parameter of constructor "Autofac"

Tags: c#, autofac

I have `class A` which implements `interface B`

`Class A` has property `Prop` with `get` and also injected `B`. Structure is like below

```
public class A : B
{
  private readonly B _interface;
  public Uri Prop {get;}

  public A (Uri uri)
  {
    _interface = MethodA(uri);
    Prop = uri;
  }
}
```

In another controller `C` I'm implementing `D` interface and injecting `interface B` like:

```
public class C:D
{
 private readonly B _interface;

 public C(B interface)
 {
   _interface=interface;
 }
}
```

So, while injecting `interface B` I'm getting an error:

`Can not resolve parameter "System.Uri uri" of constructor 'Void .ctor...'`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show your component registration for these classes

Comment: it's like: services.AddScoped<B,A>(); services.AddScoped<D,C>(); I can not register this property

Comment: You haven't told Autofac how to resolve `Uri`

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I checked several ways, none of them worked.

Comment: Something like this, if the Uri is static: `builder.Register(c => new A(new Uri("https://..."))).As<B>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

Comment: It worked man, thanks. But for simplicity I did not add other parameters to "A" class. Actually, "A" class is like A(Logger, Uri, String, String). So, how should I pass these parameters while registering Uri?

Comment: Look into [delegate factories](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html), they solve this.

Something like this, if the string are supposed to be dynamic:
`public delegate A Factory(Uri uri, string foo, string bar);`

Autofac is smart enough to resolve the logger automagically, if it's registered.

Comment: IMO @trydis resolution is the most appropriate answer